# Why does Pillow.Image.open() display an image in jupyter and not from a terminal/console?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library, jupyter

#### TLDR

How can one know the syntax differences required between a jupyter notebook and "normal" python 
(i.e. that made in a .py file and run in a terminal with `python myfile.py`)? 
Specifically for the Pillow.Image class (e.g.)

```
PIL.Image.open('/path2file.jpg')
```

why does this display (show) and image in a jupyter notebook but not in "normal" python?

#### Background

I was running through the [image classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) for tensor flow, and started copy/pasting code snippets into PyCharm (as I don't use jupyter for development) and noted a few key differences in the jupyter notebook code and what was necessary within PyCharm (or a terminal for that matter).

The two main differences I noticed were in the line

```
PIL.Image.open(str(roses[0]))
```

First off, the import statement:

```
import PIL
```

is the only thing specified in the jupyter notebook before using the `Image.open()` method. In PyCharm the `Image` class will not resolve unless I import:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Does this imply that jupyter notebooks are importing ALL classes from a package similar to `import PIL *`? I thought this was bad practice?

Also in the jupyter notebook I notice that the rose image is displayed as suggested by the tutorial upon

```
PIL.Image.open(str(roses[0]))
```

whereas in PyCharm or a console it only loads the object into memory and shows nothing.

```
PIL.Image.open(str(roses[0])).show()
```

is necessary to actually show the image on screen, which agrees with what is specified by the [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#using-the-image-class).

So my overall question is how do you know how to code for a jupyter notebook as opposed to "normal" python code in a console/terminal/.py file/PyCharm? It seems jupyter is doing things beyond what the code calls for, so how would I as a programmer know ahead of time that I don't have to call the `.show()` method in a jupyter notebook without trial and error?

Note, I'm sure I could read through all the docs on jupyter and become an expert to answer my own question, but if someone knows of a single part of the docs that covers these kinds of differences I'd very much appreciate a summary as I'm not interested in using jupyter regularly, just want to know the major differences so I can port things to "real" python from examples like the tensor flow one given above.

Answer (score -2):

Because jupyter provide us a feature to run commands and view the output in the ide itself.  It's the feature of jupyter notebook. It becomes very easy to see the commands and output.

Comment: It appears you did not read the question thoroughly.